# Field Update via Workflow in Salesforce

Tags: workflow, field-update

In workflow criteria
A field City is updated when criteria is met
Ex- Ar>10000 then city  field Is up dated  as Kolkata

Now when we decrease the AR to 100 why city field isn't blank .
As the criteria is not met.

Comment: Are you asking why the City field, which was previously updated when criteria was met, did not undo the update when criteria is not met? Please clarify if I'm misunderstanding the situation. Automation only does what you tell it to do. Based on the info you gave, if criteria is met --> action you define is taken (ex. City is updated). If the record is updated and criteria is not met, nothing happens. If you want to make City null when AR  < 10000, you'll have to create a specific WF/action for it.

Answer (score 1):

Workflow Rules do exactly what you tell them to do when they are evaluated and the condition is true, and do nothing otherwise. You would need to have a second Workflow Rule that could undo the work of the first when the conditions are met, if that is what you want the system to do. Otherwise, nothing will be done with the conditions are not met.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.It cleared my doubts.